# How do I solve $\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x...}}}=9 \Rightarrow x=?$

Tags: radicals

$\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x...}}}=9 \Rightarrow x=?$

I'm preparing for exam.

> This question comes from metropol mat1 testbook.

Comment: \begin{eqnarray*}
\sqrt{x-9}=9
\end{eqnarray*}
Square this & solve.

Comment: Bravo . A good question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call $S=\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x...}}}$.

Square both sides:

$$x-\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x...}}=81$$
i.e.
$$
x-S=81
$$
Now $S=9$, so $x=90$.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

Put $u_1=\sqrt{x}$ and
for $ n>0$,

$$u_{n+1}=\sqrt{x-u_n}$$

for example

$$u_2=\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x}}$$
$$u_3=\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x}}}.$$

If this sequence converges, its limit should satisfy

$$L=\sqrt{x-L}$$
or

$$L^2+L-x=0$$
and
$$L=\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+4x}}{2}=9$$

thus
$$4x=(19+1)(19-1)$$
finally
$$x=90$$